# Quarto reveal presentation math font

Tags: mathjax, quarto, reveal.js

I want to display a couple math formulas in a Quarto reveal.js presentation. But when I render the slides, the math formula is not in italics (at least that's the biggest difference I notice) and some characters overlap. I add a screenshot. It may be because I changed the document fonts? Anyway, I cannot solve it.

The font-related css

```
// Assign fonts
$font-family-sans-serif: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino,
  FreeSerif, serif !default;
$presentation-heading-font: "Yanone Kaffeesatz", "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, sans-serif, !default;
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vID4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out it's actually related to the browser. In Brave doesn't display it properly. Safari does.